# Fubini's theorem and set of measure zero

Tags: real-analysis, proof-verification, proof-writing, lebesgue-measure, riemann-integration

Let A be a rectangle in $R^k$ , let B be a rectangle in $R^n$, let Q = A x B. Let f: Q $\rightarrow R$ be a bounded function. Show that if $\int_Q {f}$ exists, then $\int_{y \in B} {f(x,y)} $ (denoted by I) exits for x $\in$ A - D, where D is a set of measure zero in $R^k$.

Attempt at a solution : 
By Fubini's theorem we now that  $\int_Q {f}$ = $\int_{x \in A} \underline\int_{y \in B} {f(x,y)}$ = $\int_{x \in A} \overline\int_{y \in B} {f(x,y)}$
From above we now that $\int_{y \in B} {f(x,y)}$ exists since f isintegrable over Q. We need to show that it also exists for x $\in$ A - D. Let P = $(P_A, P_B)$ be a partition for Q, We know that $m_{R_A * R_B} \leq$$m_{R_A} \leq m_{R_{A-D}} $ and V(A-D) = V(A) - V(D) and V(D) = 0.
We can use this to show that L(f,P) $\leq L(I, P_A) \leq L(I, P_{A-D}) $ and similarly for the uper sums. and Since all three integrals will by definition exist between the inequalities at the extreme ends and since the partitions are arbitrary we can conclude that I exists for A- D, and is equal to I for A.
This is just a rough draft at an attempt at the proof, I'm not sure if its even the right idea, please let me know in particular about my argument regarding V(A-D) = V(A) and whether showing that I is integrable over A-D is the same as showing that I exists for A-D. 
Thank you

Comment: This question is unclear. You have $f:Q\to$. The function needs a codomain. Also, variables go into `$` signs in TeX, so it's `$x \in A - D$`, not `x $\in$ A - D`. What does $\int_{y\in B} f(x,y)=I$ mean? What is $I$? What does it mean for $I$ to exist (not exits)? I think you meant that the integral exists. Also, if your question is just that $\int_B f(x,y) dy$ exists, for almost every $x$, isn't that one of the statements of Fubini's theorem?

Comment: Hi, I added the codomain, sorry about the TeX errors I'm only just learning. The rest of the question is exactly as from Munkres, anything you can add to enlighten me would be greatly appreciated